# How to check role of current PostgreSQL user from Qt application?

Tags: qt, postgresql, database-design, permissions

I have an application (based on the Qt library) which uses QPSQL driver. 
In PostgreSQL, there are a few user roles defined (e.g: admin, operator, user). My application creates a connection to the Postgres server under a specified user. How can I check the user's role?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE)

```
SELECT current_user;  -- user name of current execution context
SELECT session_user;  -- session user name
```

Meaning, `session_user`  shows the role you connected with, and `current_user` shows the role you are currently operating with, for instance after calling `SET role some_other_role;`.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, if you want to know a set role from within a function with `SECURITY DEFINER`, use `current_setting('role')` as [can be seen on the mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/13906.1141711109%40sss.pgh.pa.us)

Answer (score 11):

You can check PostgreSQL user permissions with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_roles;
```